# Convert all cells to a table

Tags: matlab

I have a data cells that contain these types. The type of the first cell is string, which contains a datetime like this '2017-09-20 15:35:00'

```
celldisp(data)
{935×1 cell}    [935×1 double]    [935×1 double]    [935×1 double]    [935×1 double]    [935×1 int32]    [935×1 int32]
```

I would like to convert this to a more friendly timeseries like object. But for example, when I say

```
dataArray=table2array(data);
disp(dataArray);
```

All I see is the datetime column, not the rest of the columns of double in the table.

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you convert `data` to a table structure first and then to an array it should work:

```
Example_cell={'2017-09-20 15:35:00',3,5 ;'2017-09-20 16:35:00', 4, 7}
Example_table=table(Example_cell)
Example_array=table2array(Example_table)
```

Output:

```
Example_array = 

    '2017-09-20 15:35:00'    [3]    [5]
    '2017-09-20 16:35:00'    [4]    [7]

Example_array(1)

ans = 

    '2017-09-20 15:35:00'

Example_array(2)

ans = 

    '2017-09-20 16:35:00'

Example_array(3)

ans = [3]
```